# MagicalRecord replacing contextForCurrentThread, needs to run on iOS 5.x

Tags: magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

Which is the best way to replace contextForCurrentThread for background fetch (save is not a problem) in an app that needs to run on iOS 5.0?